# How to Upgrade Win 10 to 1803 Using Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-10-v1803, unattended

I have to upgrade Windows 10 to 1803 on several remote machines, which can be accessed by using a Remote Desktop connection.

Some months ago I used this command to install 1703 without having to answer any more dialogs and especially skipping the data protection questions after the last reboot.

```
setup.exe /auto upgrade /DynamicUpdate enable /telemetry disable
```

This does not work with 1803, so how can I upgrade to 1803 and skip all the questions?
 
And btw, how are the questions after the last reboot named in English?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/969f4ffc-14ad-4cca-a116-8ba5b9210012/rdc-to-windows-server-not-working-after-windows-10-1803-cumulative-update-kb4103721-installation?forum=winserveressentials

Comment: @David: Sorry, but the issue at TechNet is another one.

Comment: I don't think there were any questions from 1703 to 1804 that blocked post-installation boot. I'm fairly sure I've kicked off a couple of (non English language) upgrades remotely and the PCs (eventually) come back online by themselves.

Comment: @roaima: They do not have to come up, depending on the System configuration, but most of the time they are there.

Comment: How do you upgrade machines remotely?  - You mount the ISO within Windows, launch the setup.exe normally, and the upgrade will happen automatically.  You could confirm this is the case by using a Virtual Machine locally.

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry, but that is simply not the case.